# Legend not showing properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
 plt.legend('g(x) = x^3 − x + 1', loc = 'upper left')
```

I have this line of code in my program, but the legend appears just as a small box with no text in it on my graph. Any solutions?

Comment: If you have two questions, ask two questions. Make sure that it has not already been asked before. I removed the second question from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't have any artist in your plot that would produce a legend, calling `plt.legend` requires to have some proxy artist supplied to it. You can e.g. use a rectangle:

```
plt.legend([plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1)],[u'g(x) = x^3 − x + 1'], loc = 'upper left')
```

In any other case, you would provide the legend label to the artist to label,

```
plt.plot(..., label=u'g(x) = x^3 − x + 1')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the input to the legend argument in a list, like this

```
plt.legend(['g(x) = x^3 − x + 1'], loc = 'upper left')
```

Comment: No sorry that didn't work. Thank you for the suggestion.